# External command/exclude everything except

Tags: doxygen

Is there any possibility to exclude all documented functions, classes, pages from the output, except those who are specially labelled?

I have a well-documented (big) project. Most of the functions and classes are internal. However, for customers I will create a documentation about a few functions and pages (like creating an API documentation, but hiding everything behind). Is there any possibility to do this, without marking **everything** with the `@internal` command? I am looking for the opposite command.

Is there any smart way to do this with conditional documentation (`@if`)?
At the moment it is also not so easy to filter the input files by name or path and use only some.

Example:

```
## @package pyexample
#  Documentation for this module.
#  More details.

'''@external @page Public documentation
   You can call the function func(), the rest is top secret internal stuff
'''
 
## @external Documentation for a public function.
def func():
    p=PyClass()
    p.PyMethod()
 
## Documentation for a class.
#
#  More details.
class PyClass:
   
    ## The constructor.
    def __init__(self):
        self._memVar = 0;
   
    ## Documentation for a method.
    #  @param self The object pointer.
    def PyMethod(self):
        pass
     
    ## A class variable.
    classVar = 0;
```

The external documentation should only contain the page `public documentation` and the documentation of `func()`.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Do the external / non_external functions etc. already have a special name (so e.g. `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS` can be used)?

Comment: I use doxygen 1.9.1 (debian standard). But it would be possible to build the public documentation with an higher version.

Comment: The non_external functions don't have a special name. Could it be possible to apply an input filter, that removes every documentation except some code? --> external code starts with an \extern \end_extern and a parser remove everything which ist not fitting the reg_ex "\extern (.*) \end_extern"

Comment: You could try to setup such a filter, this might work (best is to test it first by removing the documentation of some functions and run doxygen over it to see the potential effect. A filter is always harder to write than removing things you expect. Regrading the filter see to it that removed lines are replaced by empty lines so line counting remains OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a parser / filter-script that does the required work, hoping it will help someone.
To use this, you need to do a few changes in the doxyfile.

The input filter discards every comment line from the applied file, except it has an @external or @end_external tag (\external \end_external is also OK).

*Changes in doxyfile for external documentation:*

```
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES = YES
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES = NO
INPUT_FILTER = "python ./external_parser.py"
VERBATIM_HEADERS = NO
```

*Changes in the doxyfile for internal documentation:*
(replace the external command by space-character.)

```
ALIASES = "external= "\
          "end_external= "
```

*Input filter script: external_parser.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
# Copyright © 2023 Mahr GmbH, author Jan Stietenroth

""" Parser to detect '@external' and '@end_external' in source code comments and only extract the content between.
    Other comment content is replaced by ''.
    Source code lines are untouched.
"""

import sys

def eprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, file=sys.stderr, **kwargs)

class ParserBase:
    # Comment signs must be arranged in ascending order @see PythonParser
    comment_start = ()
    comment_end = ()

    external_start_tokens = ("@external", r"\external")
    external_end_tokens   = ("@end_external", r"\end_external")

    prevComment = None
    relatedEndComment = None
    external_cmd = None
    external_end_cmd = None

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_comment_start(self, line):
        for commentPattern in self.comment_start:
            if commentPattern in line:
                self.prevComment = commentPattern
                idx = self.comment_start.index(commentPattern)
                self.relatedEndComment = self.comment_end[idx]
                return True
        return False

    def has_endCommit(self, line):
        if self.relatedEndComment is not None and self.relatedEndComment in line:
            return True
        return False

    def has_external(self, line):
        for ext in self.external_start_tokens:
            if ext in line:
                self.external_cmd = ext
                return True
        return False

    def has_endExternal(self, line):
        for ext in self.external_end_tokens:
            if ext in line:
                self.external_end_cmd = ext
                return True
        return False

    def parse(self, input_line):
        line = input_line
        output_line = ""

        if self.prevComment is None and self.get_comment_start(line):  # Commit starts
            tmp = input_line.split(self.prevComment, 1)
            output_line = tmp[0] + self.prevComment          # Save beginning through comment-sign
            line = tmp[1]                                    # proceed with everything behind comment-sign

        if self.prevComment is not None:           # Edit only commit lines
            if self.has_external(line):                      # Substring contains '@external'
                tmp = line.split(self.external_cmd, 1)       # extract everything after that.
                line = tmp[1]

            if self.external_cmd is not None and self.has_endExternal(line):  # If '@external' is active, and '@end_external' is in line
                tmp = line.split(self.external_end_cmd, 1)
                output_line = output_line + tmp[0]           # save everything between '@external' and '@end_external'
                line = tmp[1]                                # proceed with substring behind end_external
                self.external_cmd = None                     # reset external-marker

            if self.has_endCommit(line):                     # Save end-comment sign and the rest of the line;
                if self.relatedEndComment != "":             # for single-line comments save nothing more.
                    tmp = line.split(self.relatedEndComment, 1)
                    line = self.relatedEndComment + tmp[1]
                    output_line = output_line + line
                else:
                    output_line = output_line + " "
                self.prevComment = None
                self.relatedEndComment = None

            if self.external_cmd:                            # Multiline external command
                output_line = output_line + line

        else:                                                # No comment line
            output_line = input_line
        return output_line


class PythonParser(ParserBase):
    def __init__(self):
        # this must be arranged in ascending order ( otherwise '##' would match before '##<').
        self.comment_start = ("\"\"\"!", "\"\"\"", "\'\'\'!", "\'\'\'", "##<", "##", "#<", "#")
        self.comment_end =   ("\"\"\"", "\"\"\"", "\'\'\'", "\'\'\'", "", "", "", "")
        super().__init__()


class CParser(ParserBase):
    def __init__(self):
        # this must be arranged in ascending order.
        self.comment_start = ("/**<", "/**", "/*!<", "/*!", "///<", "///", "//!<", "//!")
        self.comment_end =   ("*/",   "*/",  "*/",   "*/",  "",     "",    "",     "")
        super().__init__()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        eprint("ERROR from "+__file__+": No inputfile: sys.argv=",sys.argv)
    inputFile = sys.argv[1]
    fileEnding = inputFile.rsplit('.', 1)[1]
    if fileEnding.lower() in ('c', 'h', 'cpp', 'hpp'):
        myParser = CParser()
    elif fileEnding.lower() == 'py':
        myParser = PythonParser()
    elif fileEnding.lower() == 'dox':
        myParser = CParser()
    # unknown file:
    else:
        eprint("WARNING from "+__file__+": Unknown file extension.")
        with open(inputFile, "r") as fp:
            for line in fp:
                print('')
        sys.exit(0)

    with open(inputFile, "r") as fp:
        for line in fp:
            print(myParser.parse(line.rstrip()))
    #   eprint("Parsing sucessful: "+inputFile)
```